# My Das Keyboard II is broken

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have a Das Keyboard II (basically a customized Cherry G80-3000 with Cherry MX blue stem switches).

One day, whilst my computer was on, I plugged in a brand new usb external HDD enclosure. The enclosure didn't work, and my keboard stopped working immeidately. I tried plugging the keyboard into a different usb port and it didn't work. I tried plugging things in to the port that the keyboard was plugged in to, and they didn't work. Other usb ports on my computer and their devices continued to work.

So essentially I have a broken keyboard and a broke USB port on my computer. This happened a couple of months ago and I have been using a different cheap keyboard for the time being.

I opened up my Das Keyboard II (which is simple to do) and there is a PCB board with some chips on it - and I am guessing that it is fried.

Do I have any hope of fixing it, or do I just buy another keyboard?

It is on my floor at the moment and every morning it makes me depressed, so I need to either throw it away or get another one soon.

Would it also be possible to buy a similar Cherry keyboard and mix and match parts?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that the interface chip is probably the only part that is actually damaged. If you get the Cherry it's based off of you may be able to take the PCB from that one and put it into your broken keyboard.

Comment: This is what I would like to do - however, I live in the UK and can't find a cherry keyboard that would be compatible. The cherry is a G80-3485LWNDE-2/02 - but i'm sure any G80 would match. I just can't find one :(

Comment: Actually, I think I just found one